# SQL Get maximum number rows where DateTime is within x seconds

Tags: sql

I have a table which amongst other things contains a DateTime column. What is the best way to get the maximum number of rows within x seconds of each other?

So if I have the following rows:

```
 1   2014-02-09 01:01:01
 2   2014-02-09 01:01:02
 3   2014-02-09 01:01:03
 4   2014-02-09 01:05:01
 5   2014-02-09 01:05:11
 6   2014-02-09 01:05:12
 7   2014-02-09 01:05:23
 8   2014-02-09 01:05:30
 9   2014-02-09 01:05:45
 10  2014-02-09 01:05:56
```

How can I get the maximum number of rows within x number of seconds of each other? I.e. If I specified 10 seconds then it would return 3 because rows 1,2 and 3 are within 10 seconds of each other. If I was to specify 60 seconds then it would return 7 (rows 3 to 10?)

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query seems to do the job (for TSQL)

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT Id, value, CNT.X
  FROM 
      tbl T1 
  OUTER APPLY
  (
     SELECT COUNT(*) X FROM tbl T2
     WHERE Datediff(second, T1.value, T2.value) BETWEEN 0 AND 10
  ) CNT
)
SELECT MAX(X) FROM CTE
```

Here is  a fiddle that will show only the CTE itself (with the count for each row):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1a323/12

Comment: Works perfectly (although it's understandably a little slow across 15 millions rows of data!) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify which DBMS you're using.

This Standard SQL should run (almost) everywhere, you just have to modify how add seconds to a timestamp:

```
SELECT MAX(cnt)
FROM
 (
    SELECT Id, value, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl t2
        WHERE t2.value BETWEEN t1.value AND t1.value + INTERVAL '10' SECOND) AS cnt
    FROM tbl AS t1 
 ) AS dt
```

Performance should be similar to KekuSemau's query.

And if you got luck your DBMS supports Windowed Aggregate Function using RANGE (e.g. Oracle), this should run faster:

```
SELECT MAX(cnt)
FROM
 (
    SELECT Id, value, 
       COUNT(*) 
       OVER (ORDER BY value 
       RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND INTERVAL '10' SECOND FOLLOWING) AS cnt
    FROM tbl AS t1 
 ) AS dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select count(*) as No_Of_Records
from tab
group by datepart(hh, datfld)
,datepart(mi, datfld),
datepart(ss,datfld)/10*10
```

See a demo here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1badb/1

Comment: This is not correct, change the first time to `01:00:59` it does not connect to the 2nd and 3rd, because you use fixed blocks, not calculated differences.